# How many distinct anagrams?

Tags: combinatorics

How many distinct anagrams of the string "bananapotato"? I know I have to use combinatorics, but I am very confused on how to start going about solving this.

Comment: Please [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Have you seen similar questions? Can you answer this question with a smaller number of letters? Can you see why the answer isn't simply $12!$?

Answer (score 2):

There are $12$ letters, and if they all differed you'd have $12!$ arrangements.  However, there are $4$ $a$s, $2$ $n$s, $2$ $o$s and $2$ $t$s, which can be interchanged without effect.  Thus the number is:

$$\frac{12!}{4! 2! 2! 2!} = 2,494,800.$$

Comment: To add: there are $4!$ ways of arranging $4$ distinct letters, but only $1$ combination for $4$ a’s. To correct for this, we divide by $4!$. The same logic can be applied to the other repeated letters.